# Connect BigQuery to Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have installed Google BigQuery and I'm trying to query from BigQuery inside of Python.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery 
client = bigquery.Client(project='aaa18')
```

But I'm getting this error and I don't know what this means :

C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/udgtlvr/untitled4/bigquery

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/udgtlvr/untitled4/bigquery", line 2, in <module>

    from google.cloud import bigquery

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>

    from google.cloud.bigquery.client import Client

  File "C:\Users\udgtlvr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\client.py", line 43, in <module>

    from google import resumable_media

ImportError: cannot import name 'resumable_media' from 'google' (unknown location)
```

What are the steps I need to do in order to get this thing work?

Comment: Looks like you are missing the dependencies of the bigquery library. Normally they are installed automatically when you "pip install". If you need to install them manually for whatever reason you can see them here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/blob/master/bigquery/setup.py#L31

Answer (score 1):

Besides what @Hitobat mentions in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031931/connect-bigquery-to-python#comment104309237_59031931) (reinstalling the [`google-cloud-bigquery`](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/) module), you could also try only installing the module that is failing, the module [`google-resumable-media`](https://pypi.org/project/google-resumable-media/).

To verify which module is missing or might be outdated, you can run the following command:

> pip freeze | grep google

This will list all the google's modules you have installed.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make sure you did install the required official packages, you should have used this source first https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/index.html

They specify the install considering you use a virtual environment

```
Windows
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv <your-env>
<your-env>\Scripts\activate
<your-env>\Scripts\pip.exe install google-cloud-bigquery
```

If you did right, installing the Google Cloud Python library usually installs the required dependencies (in your case the google-resumable-media)

```
pip install google-cloud
```

As I see your problem is more than an Anaconda/Local Python paths problem... So you may first verify where the Python Client for Google BigQuery is being installed.

If you definitely want to work with Anaconda environments, then try to install the packages from the Anaconda Navigator environments manager... That should solve the dependencies problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a service account with desired BigQuery roles and download JSON key file (example: data-lab.json). Use below code:

```
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = "data-lab.json"
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do and works fine . I use Colab/Jupyter Notebooks to access Bigquery.

**First Option is to authenticate using browser**

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

**The second option is to use service account for authentication which is explained above**

Once you are done with authentication then the below code should work

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(project='project_id')
%load_ext google.cloud.bigquery
```

Run Bigquery commands using magic link

```
%%bigquery --project project_id
select * from table limit 1
```